# get related model without loop query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1, eager-loading

#### tables:

```
products:

id | name | author_id    

authors:

id | name
```

#### models:

```
product:

public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
}
```

Then I get products:

```
$products = Product::where('name','like','username%')->get();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->author;
}
```

Is there any way to get **products** with **author** without loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for this:

```
 $products = Product::where('name','like','username%')->with('author')->get();
```